# git showing more files changed than i touched

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm not new, but still struggling with git.  in particular merge vs. rebase.  the current result is that when i go to github.com to look at my feature branch (last commit) , it tells me that 152 files were changed, with 6,099 additions....  I'd estimate more like 30 files.  And indeed, the changes shown are certainly not mine.

It has, admittedly, been a long-running branch (4 weeks or so) but I keep updating it with the develop branch that the team uses.  Sometimes I need to make conflict commits, but not this many.

Before I do a pull request, any thoughts on what i did wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues many times. I would suggest to raise a `PR` and in files changed tab it will only show your changes. I have had similar problem but it works perfect when you raise a PR.

Answer (score 0):

I would git ignore all of the self generating files in the project. [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) 
Just make sure that all files you do this with can be deleted from the project and the project would just remake them without causing issues.